# panningEnabled: false disable zooming

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'd like to disable panning as well as enable zooming, but once I set "panningEnabled: false" I'm not able to zoom the graph even if I manually specify "zoomingEnabled: true". How can I achieve desirable behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to zoom about a point, you have to alter the zoom value and the pan value.

It follows that if the pan value is made immutable then you can't zoom about a point.